# activity_main.xml java.lang.nullpointerexception adding digital clock android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-view

I am new to android world and trying to use digital clock in my android application main_activity just by dragging and dropping.

It shows me below error activity_main.xml java.lang.nullpointerexception

SDK Version I am using is :

```
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
   android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Kindly help.

Layout:

```
    <   
        LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Match Venue" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Inspection Date" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">        

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Inspection Time" />

                <!-- <DigitalClock
                    android:id="@+id/digitalClock1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="DigitalClock" /> -->

            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:onClick="OpenTeamActivity"
                android:text="Next" />

            <DigitalClock
                android:id="@+id/digitalClock1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="DigitalClock" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Logcat Error as,

```
        java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.<init>(SpannableStringBuilder.java:44)
            at android.text.format.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:462)
            at android.widget.DigitalClock$1.run(DigitalClock.java:87)
```

Comment: Post the code and logcat too

Comment: And your code as well.

Comment: So just to ignore the error??.. willn't it cause any code side effects in production ??

Comment: code is needed to determine NPE. Also, logcat is not complete. From Logcat, see if there is a line starting, "Caused by NullPointerException". Just below that line, there will be line number where NPE happened.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see clock in layout editor just `reduce` the `Android Version` in your `layout editor` to `2.3 or 2.2` and you will be able to see the clock.

This error will only show on `layout editor`. Don't worry. if you run the application you will see your clock.

Comment: So just to ignore the error??.. willn't it cause any code side effects in production ??

Comment: Yes ignore the error and it wont cause any code side effect but be careful as @Sieryuu said DigitalClock is deprecated in API 17 and now it no longer have any support from android team.

Comment: I am developing an app for API 8-18 and what should i do to add digital clock? if i add it says its deprecated for >17 and if i add TextClock it says you need min version API as 17.. pls help. just wondering if i add digital clock and leave for versions higher than 17 API , it that okay??